# Handling Symfony routes in axios/ajax call

Tags: reactjs, symfony

Need to pass data to server from reactjs.The js file is juts a part of the project, not a separate on. The problem with this is it seems can't found the route in  Symfony

```
profile:
path: /profile/{slug}
defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Agent:profile }
```

In AgentController

```
 public function profileAction(Request $request, $slug)
```

Reactjs file

```
   axios.get('/profile',{
        params: {
            slug:agent.slug,
            id:agent.id
        }
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res, 'the response')
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err.toString(), 'error'))
```

But I keep getting error route not found related error, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The axios request you are generating will not perform the request you need but will perform the following request without any route parameters:

```
/profile
```

While it should be the following route

```
/profile/{agent.slug}
```

You could use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for this

```js
axios.get(`/profile/${agent.slug}`)
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res, 'the response')
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err.toString(), 'error'))
```

If you don't use webpack or anything fancy you would need to concatenate the string yourself.

```js
axios.get(`/profile/` + agent.slug)
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res, 'the response')
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err.toString(), 'error'))
```

Just beware that your agent.slug parameter is never undefined.

You could also use [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) for this as you are using SymfonyFramework. Using this will enable you to use:

```
axios.get(Routing.generate('profile', {slug: agent.slug})
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res, 'the response')
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err.toString(), 'error'))
```